# Adding selective files from one branch to other

Tags: javascript, git, branching-and-merging

While developing using Javascript, as a practice we upload minified JS on the server and thus I want to keep only minified JS in my Master Branch while I make changes on my local (private) branch. Is there a simple way to merge only the minified JS from local branch to the Master?

Cherry Pick commits wont work as I do not wish to merge all the files from my private commit. [This method](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) suggests picking up specific files from one branch to commit in other, I was wondering if there is a setting/alternate way to automate this i.e. merge only takes minified js files (*.min.js)?

Comment: Why is it a problem that you have both the unminified or minified code in `master`? It sounds like you're looking to complicate things for little benefit. (Avoiding having a bunch of tiny unused files on the server.)

Comment: Also, there are better solutions for this elsewhere than in source control. You could minify the JS on-demand in your application code, or using a tool (say, [`grunt`](http://gruntjs.com/)) that's run during deployment.

Comment: @millimoose because master branch is shared with clients to whom I do not want to expose the unminified code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a remote repo *in your document root* that you're pushing to and using that as a deployment mechanism to your live site. Having a git repo in a document root, I would say, isn't a great way to deploy. (Anyone could clone your entire repo, including your entire commit history and potentially embarrassing un-released code.) Maybe you have it set up differently, but I'll go with this assumption based on what you wrote.

If, instead, you use a post-receive hook to extract `master` to your document root, but let your git repo live somewhere else, you can then store your minified and non-minified JS source without fear.

Move your git repo out of your document root on your staging server.

In `.git/hooks/post-receive` on your staging web server:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/your/docroot git archive master --format tar | tar -x "*.min.js"
```

This will cause `git` to export a clean copy of the `master` branch to the directory of your choosing. It will do this by piping through `tar`, which you can use to filter exactly which files you want going out there and which you do not. `post-receive` is a shell script, so you can really go wild here, adding subsequent lines to do any housekeeping you'd like after a deployment.

So, the above is what I'd recommend you do. If you still want to go ahead and keep only a subset of files in your master branch, you can employ the method you linked to in a shell script.

Assuming your local branch name is `local`, and everything you want to 'deploy' to `master` is already committed, make a `deploy.sh` (and add it to `.gitignore` if you want):

```
#!/bin/sh
git checkout master
git diff-tree --name-only -r local | grep ".min.js$" > temp_file_list.txt
git checkout local `sed 'N;s/\n/ /' temp_file_list.txt`
git commit -m "Selective 'merge' of minified js from my local branch"
```

Then you just run `deploy.sh` whenever you want to update master with changed .min.js files. If you are using Windows and keep your local files in DOS format, you should put `\r\n` instead of just `\n` in the `sed` command above--and have the bash-based command line git tools installed.

Comment: No is not about using remote repo being used as a live site. My requirement is more about sharing only certain files while keeping the rest as private in my local repos. I think your second method might work. Will try that out on Monday and get back, thanks!